# Why does MySQL find an error in the CONCAT statement?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to write a stored procedure in MySQL, where I need to loop on a cursor, and execute an SQL statement that uses a piece of data from the cursor that gets fetched into a variable, then executed as SQL. The cursor orders_cur is sorted on this_addr; in a given block of this_addr records, the first record is skipped, and the rest need to be flagged by setting the duplicateorder="1".

For some reason, I cannot get the line with the CONCAT function to work without giving me an error:

```
            OPEN orders_cur;
            order_loop: LOOP
                -- Now loop on orders_cur until this_addr = match_addr
                find_addr_loop: REPEAT
                    FETCH orders_cur INTO this_addr,this_orderid;
                UNTIL this_addr = match_addr
                END REPEAT;
                -- Skip the first order that matched by performing another fetch
                FETCH orders_cur INTO this_addr,this_orderid;
                -- Now start next loop which does the real work; set duplicateorder on the remaining records in cursor,
                -- using the orders_cur.order_id to locate the actual record in the Reservations table. 
                set_dupe_loop: WHILE this_addr = match_addr
                    SET @sql = CONCAT('UPDATE Reservations SET duplicateorder = \'1\' WHERE order_id=',this_orderid);
                    PREPARE runme FROM @sql;
                    EXECUTE runme;
                    FETCH orders_cur INTO this_addr,this_orderid;
                END WHILE set_dupe_loop:;
                DEALLOCATE PREPARE runme;
            END LOOP order_loop;
```

I have tried every variation possible on escaping the literals that I need around the '1' to no avail, and am going cross-eyed...if anyone sees where my error lies, I would very much appreciate it...

--rixter

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the DECLARE for `this_orderid`? Edit: Nevermind, probably, see answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a cursor for this operation.  You can do:

```
UPDATE Reservations r JOIN
       (SELECT this_addr, MIN(order_id) as minoi
        FROM Reservations r2 
        WHERE this_addr = match_addr
        GROUP BY this_addr
       ) dups
       ON r.this_addr = dups.this_addr and r.order_id > dups.minoi
    SET r.duplicateorder = 1;
```

In general, you should avoid cursors, especially those that require dynamic SQL.  When you can express the logic as a set operation, it is usually best to do so.

Comment: This worked, once I made some minor corrections (also, I gave the wrong table name, should be _orders):  UPDATE _orders r JOIN
       (SELECT addressmatch, MIN(order_id) as minoi
        FROM _orders r2 
        WHERE orderdate >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY )
        GROUP BY addressmatch
       ) dups
       ON r.addressmatch = dups.addressmatch and r.order_id > dups.minoi
    SET r.duplicateorder = 1;

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with the CONCAT, the loop is not initiated/enclosed properly.

This `set_dupe_loop: WHILE this_addr = match_addr`

should be this `set_dupe_loop: WHILE this_addr = match_addr DO`